# ASP site's default.aspx showing up on Servers browser but NOT on Local browsers

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

Some background:

We have a project that uses an old Crystal Reports website and also a new version of the website to serve both sides of our business. Locally we are able to run both websites and on our local testing server (Windows Server 2008 R2 w/IIS7). Our testing was completed for both of these and now we have moved our sites into a Quality Assurance server in order for them to verify before we move to production.

Our newest website was deployed to this QA server and is currently being used and tested, not a problem! But when we moved the old website (which I had recently rewritten, compiled, to align with our newest standards) from our local testing server to the QA server we are experiencing quite a few problems and I believe it may be configuration related but am unsure.

**Problem #1: The old site can be accessed on the QA servers IE browser and the default.aspx page shows as anticipated. When we try to hit this URL from our local machines we are getting net:ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. The page will not display.**

The site is set up to use anonymous authentication and has all of the same handlers and settings (supposedly) on our QA Server as our Local Test Server. We browsed through a couple hours worth of possible resolutions and did not find one that could solve our issue.

I assume problem #2 may also be related...

**Problem #2: after accessing our old sites default.aspx page (in IE) on our QA server we then click on a link which brings us to another aspx page. When the link is clicked, the browser is prompting us to save or open the .aspx file.**

We have tried accessing the site through a few different browsers, clearing browser caches, but still getting the same error and behaviour.

**NOTE: I tried to layout the question as best as I could. Questions and edits are welcomed if we can more accurately describe the problem!
OLD SITE = this is our legacy reporting site, written in VB, utilizing CR. This one is having all the problems! Working in 2/3 environments.
NEW SITE = this is the new site which is basically an expansion of the old site but serves a different clientele for our business. written in C#, utilizing CR. This site is working like a charm in all 3 environments.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was all caused by the fact our site admin had the site running under port 83 instead of the default port 80 for HTTP. After I switched the site to run under port 80, all of these problems disappeared. I assume that port 83 was not able to serve the web page due to some type of security issue on the QA server (I didn't look into it any further once serving from port 80 began to work). The site that was working across the board... well, it was being served on port 80...

I didn't think it would cause the problems it did! Hopefully this answer will help someone else out in the future if they experience these same issues!